# Cannot edit use variable in anonymous PHP function

Tags: php

I'm trying to map my query to add some custom key value to the query. If there is are some same ID's then mark it as one shipment.

for example my query(collection) looks like this:

```
[
{
ID: "5835910",
TrackingNr: "06215068123019",
TrackingURL: "http://exmaple-website?trackingnr=06215068123019"
},
{
ID: "5835910",
TrackingNr: "06215068123020",
TrackingURL: "http://exmaple-website?trackingnr=06215068123020"
},
{
ID: "5860771",
TrackingNr: "06215068129534",
TrackingURL: "http://exmaple-website?trackingnr=06215068129534"
},
{
ID: "5860771",
TrackingNr: "06215068129535",
TrackingURL: "http://exmaple-website?trackingnr=06215068129535"
},
....
]
```

my result should be like this:

```
[
{
    Shipment: 1
    ID: "5835910",
    TrackingNr: "06215068123019",
    TrackingURL: "http://exmaple-website?trackingnr=06215068123019"
    },
    {
    Shimpent: 1
    ID: "5835910",
    TrackingNr: "06215068123020",
    TrackingURL: "http://exmaple-website?trackingnr=06215068123020"
    },
    {
    Shimpent: 2
    ID: "5860771",
    TrackingNr: "06215068129534",
    TrackingURL: "http://exmaple-website?trackingnr=06215068129534"
    },
    {
    Shipment: 2
    ID: "5860771",
    TrackingNr: "06215068129535",
    TrackingURL: "http://exmaple-website?trackingnr=06215068129535"
    },
    ....
]
```

i've tried to map my query ad a shipment key to the array and set an counter for the value. But it's not working as i expected. My counter ist not counting properly.

```
 $counter = 1;                          

        $tracking = $tracking->map(function($item, $key) use ($tracking, $counter) {

            if(isset($tracking[$key + 1])) {
                if($item->BelID != $tracking[$key + 1]->BelID) {
                    $counter = $counter + 1;

                }
            }

            return [
                'Shipment' => $counter, 
                'ID' => $item->BelID,
                'TrackingNr' => $item->TrackingNr,
                'TrackingURL' => $item->TrackingURL
            ];

        });
        return $tracking;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to give permission for variables in anonymous functions to be able to be changed by adding `&` before the `$`:

```
use ($tracking, &$counter)
```

Comment: Wow, that helped me a lot !